# Django Unexpected 405 Response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, http-status-code-405

1. Problem

   My django application often respond `405 Method Now Allowed` even though 
   it's working api on development environment. But if i restart 
   development server (`python manage.py runserver`) It works.
2. Environment

   - macOS Mojave 10.14
   - Python 3.6.4 (Isolated environment via Pipenv)
   - Django 2.1.4
   - djangorestframework 3.8.2
3. API Code

   settings/urls.py (root url file)

   ```
   from django.urls import path, include

   import my_account.urls

   urlpatterns = [
       path('account/', include(my_account.urls, namespace='account_v1')),
   ]
   ```

   my_account/urls.py

   ```
   from django.urls import path

   from .apps import MyAccountConfig
   from .views import TokenView

   app_name = MyAccountConfig.name

   urlpatterns = [
       path('token/', TokenView.as_view()),
   ]
   ```

   my_account/views.py

   ```
   from rest_framework.views import APIView

   class TokenView(APIView):
       def post(self, request):
           # Some Business-Logic Code
           pass
   ```
4. Log

   Log when 405 occured

   ```
   System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
   December 07, 2018 - 11:22:54
   Django version 2.1.4, using settings 'my_server.settings.staging'
   Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
   Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
   .env Applied
   [07/Dec/2018 11:24:30] "OPTIONS /account/token/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
   [07/Dec/2018 11:24:30] "{"email":"email@hidden.com","password":"hidden_password"}POST /account/token/ HTTP/1.1" 405 66
   ```

   Log when working

   ```
   System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
   December 07, 2018 - 11:48:01
   Django version 2.1.4, using settings 'my_server.settings.staging'
   Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
   Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
   .env Applied
   [07/Dec/2018 11:48:08] "OPTIONS /account/token/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
   [07/Dec/2018 11:48:09] "POST /account/token/ HTTP/1.1" 200 517
   ```

   In chrome network tab, no difference between request for 200 and 405.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have faced this same error for the last two months eventually I Solved at the end. 
Error:
When a user token is become expired we will be getting 401 status code with unauthorized message, when this happens the next API is also getting interrupted it returns 405 Method Not Allowed as an error.
Solution : 
There was a bug issue in Django version 2.1 you have to upgrade your django version to 2.2.

After that check this error it will not raise.

Answer (score 0):

> HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED

The **status code 405** represents that you are requesting in a method that is not allowed.
Based on your code, You are defining Token API to be accessible by `post` method.

look at this log:

```
[07/Dec/2018 11:48:09] "POST /account/token/ HTTP/1.1" 200 517
```

in this you are sending clear `POST` request which will be ok. but look at the provided log for failed cases:

```
[07/Dec/2018 11:24:30] "{"email":"email@hidden.com","password":"hidden_password"}POST /v1/account/token/ HTTP/1.1" 405 66
```

1- For some reason in your UI, you are sending a request with method `{"email":"email@hidden.com","password":"hidden_password"}POST`!!!!.

2- and you are sending request to `/v1/account/token/` API endpoint which is not registered in your urls at all (based on what info you gave us)

Comment: Sorry, `/v1/account/token/` was my typo mistake. And, in chrome inspection, request was valid and has no difference. (Also, same in packet capture tool)